# LazyVim: Is there a simple way to enable automatic dark/light color toggle?

Tags: themes, neovim

I am trying to switch from VSCode to Neovim and use LazyVim for my setup, which I run on WezTerm. I like the IDE it provides, but I would like to know if I can have an automatic light/dark mode switch like I had in VSCode. See, in VSCode, I could set up my preferred light and dark themes in `settings.json`, and the IDE would change its color automatically when my OS preferred color changes (I am on Pop!_OS, based on Ubuntu 24).

I have been looking for a solution these last days and tried many workarounds unsuccessfully, like storing and updating the preferred theme in a file and make Neovim watch for this file to change (that one did not work because I seemingly cannot change `vim.o.background` or `vim.o.colorscheme` in a callback function).

I would be glad if there was a simple solution that did not require me to write and/or modify dozens files myself.

Thank you for your help.